# List of words affected by the 1901 spelling reform

Tags: spelling, history

Is there a list anywhere (in book form or online, though the latter is preferable) of words that were affected by the 1901 orthographic reform? (The one that changed Th to T in native words, replaced C with Z and K, etc., *not* the 1996 one.)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://archive.org/details/Regeln-fuer-die-deutsche-Rechtschreibung ?

Comment: You may refer to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901.

Comment: Such a list could only exist in relation to one of the several competing older orthographies since the 1901 ruleset was the first (almost) universally accepted one.

Comment: While I cannot provide a list of the changed words, and as mentioned before, you may add https://archive.org/details/regelnundwrterv00unkngoog (from 1859) and compare the words listed there with those mentioned in archive.org/details/Regeln-fuer-die-deutsche-Rechtschreibung (after the mentioned reform)

Answer (score 1):

No, nobody has done the work of printing out a difference list between the Duden before and after the reform. You have the new Duden of 1903 and that's it.[<sup>(1)</sup>](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901)

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary contains some of the pre-1901 spellings. The entries seem to be marked as follows: `{{Alte Schreibweise|Publikum|Reform 1901}}`, see for example
https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Publicum

From the dump dewiktionary-20191020-pages-articles.xml, I can extract 1771 spelling changes (not always base forms, but also inflected forms). If anyone is interested in details, let me know.